# Как в ComboBox вывести дату "закрыто с ...", приходящую с сервера?

Tags: javascript, дата, extjs

Необходимо в списке кафедр (`department`) для каждой вывести дату закрытия кафедры, приходящую с сервера, при условии, что дата превышает текущую.

```
{ 
    xtype: 'combobox', 
    fieldLabel: 'Кафедра', 
    store: 'dict.Department', 
    queryMode: 'local', 
    displayField: 'name', 
    valueField: 'id', 
    width: 600, 
    name: 'department', 
    selectOnFocus: true, 
    listeners: 
    { 
        beforequery: function(qe){ 
            qe.query = new RegExp(qe.query, 'i');        
            qe.forceAll = true; 
            filters = this.store.filters.items; 
            this.store.filter(filters); 
        } 
    } 
    //editable: false 
}
```

Comment: Покажите что сделали сами, здесь не приветствуется работа за автора. Пока это выглядит как работа за автора, вы не только не привели пример ваших попыток, но даже не можете правильно указать, какой фреймворк используете.

Comment: @MakarovAV, я задаю вопрос на stackoverflow в первый раз... сама еще ничего толком не сделала т.к. не знаю где и что именно писать. по ходу даже кусок кода не тот скинула сюда (в следующем комменте залью нужный)... дали задание дополнить выпадающий список кафедр датой закрытия каждой из них... что касается фреймворка, то это ExtJS 4.2

Comment: { xtype: 'combobox',
fieldLabel: 'Кафедра',
store: 'dict.Department',
queryMode: 'local',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
width: 600,
name: 'department',
selectOnFocus: true,
listeners: {
beforequery: function(qe) {
qe.query = new RegExp(qe.query, 'i');
qe.forceAll = true;
filters = this.store.filters.items;
this.store.filter(filters);
}
}
//editable: false
},

Comment: @MakarovAV, мне хотелось бы хоть чуть-чуть понять, какую часть этого кода надо изменить и как именно... ExtJS не знаю, учусь с нуля по мере выполнения заданий на работе...

Comment: ага Ext я узнал, потому и сказал. Исправьте основной вопрос (кнопка "править") и отправьте на переоткрытие, как видите код в комментариях не форматируется

Comment: всё, нашла, как форматировать код в вопросе) переоткрыла)

Comment: если вопрос переоткроют, то напишу подробно ближе к вечеру. Если вкратце, то: 1. Есть две сущности, комбобокс который отвечает за отображение и хранилище, в котором содержатся данные. 2. Если в хранилище данные уже есть, то вам надо перекрыть у комбобокса свойство tpl и написать там шаблон отображения http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-tpl, если данных нет, то потребуются дальнейшие уточнения

Answer (score 1):

Итак, в ExtJs [`combobox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) обычно получает некие данные из хранилища ([`store`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)) и показывает их.
Самый распространенный тип хранилища, если все очень-очень сильно упростить, представляет из себя некоторый массив объектов (рекордов), каждый из которых `combobox` и показывает

Обычно (в вашем примере) мы связываем комбобокс с хранилищем с помощью конфига [`store`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-store), а в конфиге [`dispalyName`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-displayField) говорим комбобоксу какое свойство объекта мы хотем в нем показывать.

Собственно я предполагаю, что **первый вопрос** в топике - как сделать так чтобы данные отображаемые комбобоксом формировались на основе нескольких полей рекордов из хранилища. Это замечательно описано в [официальной документации по комбобоксу](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox)  в разделе "Customized combobox". Официальная документация экста прекрасна, всегда ищите сначала в ней.

Итак, у комбика есть два конфига: [`tpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-tpl) который служит для отображения того что мы видим в выпадающем списке и [`displayTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-displayTpl) для отображения того что мы видим в соответствующем текстфилде. Если Вы их используете, то конфиг `displayName` разумеется не нужен. Эти конфиги могут принимать в себя экземпляр класса [`ExtTemplate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) - это встроенный в ExtJs шаблонизатор. Прям в шаблоне если надо можно делать циклы, условия и математику, впрочем это видно по докам.

Соответственно вам надо указать шаблон как-нибудь так:

```
    { 
        xtype: 'combobox', 
        ...
        tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
           '<tpl for=".">',
               '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{name} - {date}</div>',
           '</tpl>'
        ),
        // template for the content inside text field
        displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<tpl for=".">',
                           '{name} - {date}',
            '</tpl>'
        )
    }
```

Это покажет все в формате кафедра-дата, разумеется если у вас в хранилище есть дата в поле date.

**Второй вопрос** в топике - как сравнить между собой две даты. Раз уж у вас Ext, то разумно использовать методы объекта [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Date), с помощью которого вы можете распарсить дату в любом распространенном формате и сделать много чего полезного. Там нет сравнения дат, потому что дата представляется в миллисекундах, а их можно сравнить как обычно. Учтите что вам нужно сравнивать именно даты, без времени. То есть что-то вроде;

```
var yourDate = Ext.Date.clearTime(Ext.Date.parse(...)),
    now = Ext.Date.clearTime(Ext.Date.now());
    if(yourDate < now){
      // Ну там какой-нибудь код
    }
```

**Третий вопрос**, как это все связать, потому что не думаю что такую проверку прожует шаблонизатор (да и что вообще что надо ее в таком виде туда класть)

Тут с ходу не могу сказать как сделать хорошо, можно например сделать поле в хранилище, которое заполняется датой если нам подходит, и нет - в другом случае, и проверять в шаблоне заполнено оно или нет, можно *аккуратно* перекрыть метод, в котором данные из хранилища уезжают на шаблон (с ходу не помню какой). Можно посмотреть поддерживает ли экстовый шаблонизатор хелперы и впилить проверку там если поддерживает.

Comment: Буду читать официальную документацию и разбираться дальше в Ext! Вы мне здорово помогли - теперь хотя бы есть от чего отталкиваться! Спасибо огромное!